# Django admin filters in custom template

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I want to implement django admin filters in my custom template  can any body from you help me in resolving this issue i will appreciate.  i am getting this error      ...... *name 'AddFilter' is not defined*...

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField()
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.DateField()
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price', 'release_date']
```

**views.py**

```
def filt_page(request):
    filter = AddFilter(request.GET, queryset=Add.objects.all())
    print (filter)
    return render_to_response('filt_page.html',{'filter':filter})
```

**template**

```
<form action="" method="get"> {% csrf_token %}
            {{ filter.form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

         {% for obj in filter %}
            {{ obj.name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Add more details....

Comment: I tried date range filter that works fine ..But i am looking for something similar to admin in django.

Comment: Your question is downvoted not because they don't know the answer, but because you hadn't provided enough info on what have you tried so far, and where have you failed

Comment: Thanks Pardeep adding comment.

Comment: its fine now so please help me guys..

Answer (score 0):

You've called an undefined class in your views.py

class name in filters.py is 'ProductFilter' but you've called 'AddFilter' in views.py

Also the model name in your filter is undefined, you've used 'Add' instead of 'Product'

Try

```
filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
```